# Implement Virtual scrolling in angular 6

Tags: angular, angular-material

How do I implement Virtual Scroll in angular 6?
Can we use `ScrollDispatchModule` for that and how can we do using it?

Answer (score 1):

please prooceed go to link and you will find a example
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cdk-demo-virtual-scroll