# Implement Virtual scrolling in angular 5

Tags: angular, angular-material, infinite-scroll, virtualscroll, angular-cdk-virtual-scroll

How do I implement Virtual Scroll in angular 5?
I tried this [Implement Virtual scrolling in angular 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58448096/implement-virtual-scrolling-in-angular-6) in angular 5 project but this didn't work. Is there any other way to implement virtual scroll in angular 5?

lets say I have a component displaying the data like this

```
<div *ngFor="let x of data">
  {{x}}
</div>
```

and the value of the data is

```
 public data=[]
  constructor() { 
    for(let i=0;i<1000000000;i++){
      this.data.push(`testing ${i}`)
    }
  }
```

now this list hangs for such large data set? So I need to add virtual scroll in this component so that it function like first example in https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cdk-demo-virtual-scroll?file=package.json

Comment: Please post some code.

Comment: @hrdkisback gave an example in the question, hope this is okay.